# Converting Matplotlib plots to Plotly Line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have a code which will plot multiple plots using matplotlib.My code is give below.

```
index = LFRO_tdms["Measurement Config"].as_dataframe()["Frequencies"]
for vdd in set_vdds:
    for DUT in unique_DUTs:
        temp_df = df[ (df["Serial"] == str(DUT)) & (df["VDD (V)"]==vdd) ]
        temp_df["Serial ID - Temp(C)"] = temp_df["Serial"] + " - " + temp_df["Target Temp (°C)"].astype(dtype=str)
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot = df_LFRO[temp_df["#Magnitude"].to_numpy(dtype=str)]
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot.index = index
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot.columns = temp_df["Serial ID - Temp(C)"]
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot.plot(logx=True, colormap="jet")
        plt.title("Unit: "+ DUT + " Vdd: " + str(vdd))
```

afetr running this code it will output multiple plots 12 0r 13 nos as shown below.

[image]

I need to implement the same using plotly.below is my code,but it is outputting plots in a different way.

```
fig = go.Figure()
index = LFRO_tdms["Measurement Config"].as_dataframe()["Frequencies"]
for vdd in set_vdds:
    for DUT in unique_DUTs:
        temp_df = df[ (df["Serial"] == str(DUT)) & (df["VDD (V)"]==vdd) ]
        temp_df["Serial ID - Temp(C)"] = temp_df["Serial"] + " - " + temp_df["Target Temp (°C)"].astype(dtype=str)
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot = df_LFRO[temp_df["#Magnitude"].to_numpy(dtype=str)]
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot.index = index
        df_LFRO_data_to_plot.columns = temp_df["Serial ID - Temp(C)"]
        
#         df_LFRO_data_to_plot.plot(logx=True, colormap="jet")
#         plt.title("Unit: "+ DUT + " Vdd: " + str(vdd))
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df_LFRO_data_to_plot.index, y=df_LFRO_data_to_plot.columns, mode='lines', name = ("Unit: "+ DUT + " Vdd: " + str(vdd))))
        fig.show()
```

[image]

I need the plots to come as shown in the 1st image. May I know what mistake I am making.

```
    Test    Station Position    Serial  Timestamp   ETC Temp (°C)   ETC Pressure (kPa)  ETC Humidity (%RH)  Ref Mic Temp (°C)   Site Temp (°C)  Target Temp (°C)    VDD (V) LFRO (Hz)   #Magnitude
0   1   1   1   07LX-1  2022-11-17 23:05:51.591926  23.151848   99.334515   3.564379    14.349645   -30.041135  -35.0   1.60    9.221194    0
1   1   1   2   07LX-2  2022-11-17 23:05:51.591926  23.151848   99.334515   3.564379    14.349645   -30.257592  -35.0   1.60    8.995556    1
2   1   1   3   07LX-3  2022-11-17 23:05:51.591926  23.151848   99.334515   3.564379    14.349645   -30.511629  -35.0   1.60    9.452866    2
3   1   1   4   07LX-4  2022-11-17 23:05:51.591926  23.151848   99.334515   3.564379    14.349645   -29.863173  -35.0   1.60    9.299079    3
4   1   1   1   07LX-1  2022-11-17 23:09:41.373825  22.475499   99.338778   3.574306    12.311989   -28.114924  -35.0   1.66    7.390171    4
```

Comment: Is the y-axis value a string? Can you present sample data?

Comment: Added the sample data.Y axis is not a string if you see the 1st two matplotlib plots you can see y axis values like 0,-0.5 etc

Comment: Is the first column of the sample data an index? And what do set_vdds and uniqueDUTs in the loop process represent?